# Какой лучший способ сохранить даты?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-shared-preferences

У меня есть база данных, куда я сохраняю название привычки и другие данные. Также я хочу сохранить очень много дат из календаря (у каждой привычки свое множество дат).

1. Что лучше использовать - sharedPreferences или SQLite?
2. Какой наилучший способ сохранить даты одной привычки, чтобы они не перемешались с датами другой привычки, и я могла их все быстро
   достать (или хотя бы все даты для одного месяца для данной привычки)?
3. И в каком формате их лучше хранить (String, int)?

Answer (score 1):

1. Если дат не много - используйте sharedPreferences. Если много (думаю десятки и больше) и по ним нужно будет делать разные выборки, SQLite будет значительно удобнее.
2. Тут сложно сказать точно, надо смотреть целевую задачу, но возможно, для этого нужна будет одна таблица с двумя столбцами дата и id привычки. Конечно, будет ещё одна таблица, где по id привычки будет храниться имя.
3. Дату лучше сохранять в виде DateTime (для sqlite это просто [INTEGER](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) ) и тогда станет сразу доступна куча [полезных функций](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Чтобы выбрать все даты для какой-то привычки для текущего месяца, можно посмотреть в этот вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36820890/select-data-from-current-month-in-android-with-sqlite

и составить где-то такой запрос:

```
SELECT hdate 
FROM habbits
WHERE
  strftime('%Y',hdate) = strftime('%Y',date('now'))
  AND
  strftime('%m',hdate) = strftime('%m',date('now'))
```

Comment: Я могу сохранить даты типа Calendar вместо Integer  в бд? 
Мне же не нужно создавать новый класс для календаря для привычек (сделать 2 разных файла с датабазами, но класс для привычки 1)?

Comment: можно в базе сохранить почти все что угодно. Но обычно в базе сохраняют так, что бы удобно было делать запросы. Потому что лучше в базе отфильтровать и отсортировать, чем вытягивать все данные и делать то же самое в коде. Создавать два файла базы данных не нужно, в одной базе можно создать просто две (или больше) таблицы.

Comment: Как сохранить дату или передать ее в базу как Integer? Я перепробовала много способов, но ни один не подходит.

Comment: там есть [time](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar#time) - это как раз то, что Вам нужно

Answer (score 0):

Дату всегда нужно хранить в формате long